@available guard/weak linking not compiling
I'm trying to use a different property names for a future macOS version due to deprecation. Specifically, NSCursor.columnResizeCursor is available on 15.0+, but I'm using the 14.0 SDK.
I read that @available guards are the correct way to handle this. However, the code below does not compile when ran with
clang -mmacos-version-min=10.14 -weak_framework AppKit main.m.
The error is
error: property 'columnResizeCursor' not found on object of type 'NSCursor'
Is there anything I am doing wrong? I was under the impression that weak linking the AppKit framework wouldn't have it complain about missing properties.
// main.m

#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main() {
    if (@available(macOS 15.0, *)) {
        // This line does not compile!
        [NSCursor.columnResizeCursor set];
    } else {
        [NSCursor.resizeLeftRightCursor set];
    }
}


macOS 14 doesn't know about macOS 15 APIs, hence the error. Build with Xcode 16 on a Mac with macOS 15 to use macOS 15 APIs.
